# Separation of UI from the event handlers

Tags: java, events, event-handling

Why is it better to separate the source of the events (e.g. buttons) from the place where the event is dealt with (i.e. event handlers)?

Answer (score 1):

For one, GUIs are inherently difficult to test.  If you can successfully remove most/all application logic from your GUI, then all code that needs to tested will be in a separate class (that has no GUI widgets) that can now easily be tested under JUnit.

Comment: in addition to this, you can have multiple ways to trigger an event, for example ctrl+s and a "save" button. If you extract the code that does the saving to a separate entity you can reuse it.